# Disable item link for specific products in WooCommerce cart checkout and orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, permalinks

I would like to disable the link from cart items and order items names for specific variable products.

I found *[Disable item name link for specific product in Woocommerce cart checkout and orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408675/disable-item-name-link-for-specific-product-in-woocommerce-cart-checkout-and-ord/55409225#55409225)* answer code that does disable links on single product, but I would like to know how to change it for a variables one?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow Rita, please tell what you have done exactly and show the point in which the issue occurs that way you can get an answer more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work **with all product types** (simple, variable,  variations…), disabling item links from an array of **defined product Ids**:

```
// Cart item link
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'conditionally_remove_link_from_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function conditionally_remove_link_from_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // HERE set your products IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array(37, 40);

    if( array_intersect($product_ids, array($cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id']) ) ) {
        $item_name = $cart_item['data']->get_name();
    }
    return $item_name;
}

// Mini-cart item link
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', 'conditionally_remove_cart_item_permalink', 10, 3 );
function conditionally_remove_cart_item_permalink( $permalink, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // HERE set your products IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array(37, 40);

    if( array_intersect($product_ids, array($cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id']) ) ) {
        $permalink = '';
    }
    return $permalink;
}

// Order item link
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'conditionally_remove_link_from_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
function conditionally_remove_link_from_order_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {
    // HERE set your products IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array(37, 40);

    if( array_intersect($product_ids, array($item->get_product_id(), $item->get_variation_id()) ) ) {
        $item_name = $item->get_name();
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Perfect, now I understand how to use it. Thanks so much.